# Error al mostrar un div en función del valor seleccionado (FORMULARIO)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, formularios

Buenas tardes a todos,

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente , mostrar un div que contiene otro input, solamente si en el select "deporte", está seleccionado el valor 'Si', en caso contrario, no lo mostraremos.

Código HTML ->

**Select "deporte"** -> si se selecciona la opción "Si" , mostramos div con id "deporte-dias".

```
<div class="col-md-5 ">
            <label for="deporte">Entrenas actualmente ( gimasio..calistenia.. ejercicio múscular)</label>
                <select class="form-control deporte" name="deporte" >
                        <option value="No">No</option>              
                        <option value="Si">Si</option>                      
                </select>
        </div>
```

**Select "deporte-dias"** -> Este solo se mostrará solamente si en el select anterior, se selecciona "Si".

```
<div class="form-row justify-content-center" id="deporte-dias">
        <div class="col-md-4 " >
            <label for="deporte-dias">Cúantos dias a la semana entrenas?</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="deporte-dias">
                        <option value="1">1</option>                
                        <option value="2">2</option>                        
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">Todos los días de la semana</option>
                </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Lo he intentado con varios scripts, que he ido viendo, personalmente el que mas funcionable y simple ha sido este :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select[name='deporte']").change(function(){
                if ($(select[name=deporte]>option:checked).val=='Si'){
                    $("#deporte-dias").css({"display":"inline"});
                }else{
                    $("#deporte-dias").css({"display":"none"});
                }
        })});
```

Lo que pasa es que los cierres creo que están mal, y puede ser por eso que no me haga la función.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, si corres tu código en la consola verás que tienes un error de sintaxis.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Por lo que tienes que verificar tu código:

En el `if ($(select[name=deporte]>option:checked).val=='Si')`:

- El selector está incorrecto, tiene que estar entre comillas `$("select[name=deporte]>option:checked")`
- No es necesario agregar el atributo de `option:checked` este es para los input tipo: **`checkbox`**
- Para obtener el valor se necesita agregar los paréntesis ya que es una función, de la siguiente manera: `$('select[name=deporte]').val()`

De esta manera podemos obtener el valor y compararlo.
Siguiendo con tu fragmento código modifique el **HTML** para darle un formato de formulario. Así queda de una manera más simple y ordenada.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='deporte']").change(function() {
    if ($('select[name=deporte]').val() == 'Si') {
      $("#div-deporte-dias").css({
        "display": "block"
      });
    } else {
      $("#div-deporte-dias").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="deporte">Entrenas actualmente ( gimasio..calistenia.. ejercicio múscular)</label>
    <select class="form-control deporte" name="deporte">
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Si">Si</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="div-deporte-dias">
    <label for="deporte-dias">Cúantos dias a la semana entrenas?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="deporte-dias">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">Todos los días de la semana</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Ivan-San, i have a trouble, your code works well,, but if i copy and paste, the same, it doesn't work , but if i go to console, and i also paste another time the script, it runs good.. whats the problem? cookies maybe?

Comment: Try to delete all the cache and cookies

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo el ejemplo con la solución.

lo realizado

1.- Se agregue un id al select  "deporte", entonces cuando se cambie el select se hace un opcion, 
2-.s agregue 3 igual para asegurar que el valor sea igual al que se compara.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#deporte").on('change', function() {
  if($("#deporte").val() === "Si"){
   $("#deporte-dias").css({"display":"inline"});
  }else{
   $("#deporte-dias").css({"display":"none"});
  }
});
       });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-5 " >
            <label for="deporte">Entrenas actualmente ( gimasio..calistenia.. ejercicio múscular)</label>
                <select  id="deporte" class="form-control deporte" name="deporte" >
                        <option value="No">No</option>              
                        <option value="Si">Si</option>                      
                </select>
        </div>
 
 <div class="form-row justify-content-center" id="deporte-dias"  style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-md-4 " >
            <label for="deporte-dias">Cúantos dias a la semana entrenas?</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="deporte-dias">
                        <option value="1">1</option>                
                        <option value="2">2</option>                        
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">Todos los días de la semana</option>
                </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```